# how to test api from span/admin package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-8

these are the routes for api inside span/admin package, when I test them on postman, it doesn't work, there is any prefix that I should be added other than api? and why there is no any use for the path of controller?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('{resource}/filters', FiltersController::class);

Route::post('image', ImageUpload::class);
Route::get('notifications', NotificationsController::class);
Route::post('notifications/read', NotificationsReadController::class);
Route::get('metrics', MetricsController::class);
Route::patch('candidates/{candidate}/stage', CandidateStageUpdate::class);
Route::post('avatar', AvatarUpload::class);
Route::resource('profile', ProfileController::class)->only(['create', 'store']);
Route::resource('jobs', JobsController::class);
Route::get('jobs/{job}/candidates', 'JobsController@candidates');
Route::resource('categories', CategoriesController::class);
```

Comment: Can you add more information? What is your test (code)? What error are you getting (I am assuming it cannot find the URL)? What do you mean with "_routes for API inside span/admin package_", what do you mean with `package`? A composer package? Do you have the github URL? Can you run `php artisan route:list` and show the result (as text, no images please)

Comment: @matiaslauriti I cloned this project from github, it is used the composer package (span/admin), inside it there is an api.php file in routes folder, how to test these apis? and this is the result for command                                                                                                                     ``

Comment: `span/admin` does not exist on packagist (where we find public packages that you can install using `composer require ....`). You do not test downloaded packages, the package should be test internally, same as you do not test Laravel, but the code you composed using Laravel. If you want to test the package (and looks like it is local), test it on the package itself, but I have no idea what `span/admin` is, so I do not know what you want to test. And edit the question adding the data, do not post it as a comment, please

Comment: @matiaslauriti these packages "span/admin": "*",
        "span/dummy-data": "*",
        "span/specialty": "*", are used in the project, how can I find what these packages, I searched on them but there is no any documentation or repositories

Comment: Check your composer.lock for those packages and see if there's a URL. I couldn't find them for your other question, either. As requested, can you explain about what doesn't work and what you mean by no other path for the controller?

Comment: @aynber this URLs in copmoser file                 "url": "./packages/specialty",
                "url": "./packages/dummy-data",
                "url": "./packages/admin",
i think the source for them is                 "url": "https://github.com/laranext/span.git",
.... my problem is I con't understand how to work with these packages... i try to test any api in this project but don't work

Comment: Curiously, the package for [laranext/span](https://github.com/laranext/span) says `laranext is still under production and not available publicly at the moment`. If you need help using his package, you might be better off raising an issue in their repository. Is there are particular reason why you need the laranext package?

Comment: @aynber yes, I need this package and need to know how to deal with it, because I want to build on this project for my company

Comment: I would suggest contacting the author, then. They can help you get started with using their code.